# how to filter the value base one the upper row value

Tags: r

I have a `df`:

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(Name = c("test", "a", "nb", "c", "r", "f", NA, 
"d", "ee", "test", "value", "test", "b")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I only keep the row which upper row=="test" and row value !="value"?

The new `df1` will looks like this (any of either case is Ok):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(lag(Name == "test"), Name != "value")

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  Name 
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b
```